# How Can I Remove System.Size Property from My Custom File Type On Windows Explorer?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, com, shell-extensions

I have been trying lately to get a grasp on the Windows Property System. I implemented a custom file type(Property Handler, Thumbnail Handler, Preview Handler) and I want to hide System.Size property for my file type on Windows Explorer(Details Tab on Properties dialogbox and Size Column on Details View Mode).I used the following code but no result. Is it possible to hide size property? Maybe I should write Shell Folder extension.

```
#include <shobjidl.h>
#include <propsys.h>
#include <propvarutil.h>
#include <propkey.h>
#include <strsafe.h>

#pragma comment(lib,"propsys.lib")

HRESULT SetPropertyValue(PCWSTR pszFilename, PCWSTR pszCanonicalName, PCWSTR pszValue)
{
    // Convert the Canonical name of the property to PROPERTYKEY
    PROPERTYKEY key;
    HRESULT hr = PSGetPropertyKeyFromName(pszCanonicalName, &key);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        IPropertyStore* pps = NULL;

        hr = SHGetPropertyStoreFromParsingName(pszFilename, NULL, gpsFlags, IID_PPV_ARGS(ppps));
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
           PROPVARIANT propvarValue = { 0 };
           hr = InitPropVariantFromString(pszValue, &propvarValue);
           if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
           {
               hr = PSCoerceToCanonicalValue(key, &propvarValue);
               if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
               {
                   // Set the value to the property store of the item.
                   hr = pps->SetValue(key, propvarValue);
                   if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                   {
                       // Commit does the actual writing back to the file stream.
                       hr = pps->Commit();
                       if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                       {
                           wprintf(L"Property %s value %s written successfully \n", pszCanonicalName, pszValue);
                       }
                       else
                       {
                           wprintf(L"Error %x: Commit to the propertystore failed.\n", hr);
                       }
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       wprintf(L"Error %x: Set value to the propertystore failed.\n", hr);
                   }
            }
            PropVariantClear(&propvarValue);
        }
        pps->Release();
    }
    else
    {
        wprintf(L"Error %x: getting the propertystore for the item.\n", hr);
    }
 }
 else
 {
    wprintf(L"Invalid property specified: %s\n", pszCanonicalName);
 }
 return hr;
 }



 int wmain(int argc, wchar_t* argv[])
 {
     if (SUCCEEDED(CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED | COINIT_DISABLE_OLE1DDE)))
     {
         SetPropertyValue(L"FullFilePath",L"System.Size", L"0");

         CoUninitialize();
     }
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: A property handler will add properties to a Shell Item, but if this item has other properties defined by the containing folder for example, they will be available to the end user (not necessarily visible). A Shell Item which is a file has implicitly lots of available properties, including size, dates, etc. Properties can be readonly or readwrite. Obviously, size is readonly since it's defined by the underlying storage.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but is there another way to do that?

Comment: Only if you control the Shell/View Folder, using a Shell namespace extension for example, in this case you are responsible for the items in your folder. But it can be a lot of work, it depends on what you want to do in the end.